# Creating Visual Studio 2010 Add-Ins - how to start?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vs-extensibility

I want to create a VS 2010 Add-Ins.I searched in the internet but most of guides were for VS 2008 or 2005. Can any one show me some useful guide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best place to Start with. [Extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165.aspx)

Here are some cool Code samples of existing Extensions.

[Developer Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Topic&f%5B0%5D.Value=VSX&f%5B1%5D.Type=User&f%5B1%5D.Value=Microsoft%20-%20Visual%20Studio%20Platform%20Team&f%5B1%5D.Text=Microsoft%20-%20Visual%20Studio%20Platform%20Team)

Check out the [Editor walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd441784#Extensibility) which gives you the basic and simple steps to get you started.

Have you tried `Vs Pro-power tools`:`VS->Tools->Extensions manager->Online Extensions`

This has some cool Extensions and gets updated every month or so.